# Raspberry Pi bluetooth connects but gives me this error when I try to run a script

Tags: pi-3, python, bluetooth

My question is about the raspberry pi original and raspberry pi 3 connect to the android's Bluetooth beautifully according to both the phone and pi. However, when I try to run a file I get the following error:

```
bluetoothSerial = serial.Serial("/dev/rfcomm0",baudrate = 9600 )
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 240, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 268, in open
    raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 2] could not open port /dev/rfcomm0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/rfcomm0'
```

I have a raspberry pi original that both connects to bluetooth and runs the files. The files send information to an MIT App Inventor app.

Does anyone know what the problem is?